# How can I play a video file on Android Wearable?

Tags: android, video, wear-os

Hi I am trying to play a video file on my Android wear.
The video file is located in the sdcard folder on the wearable device.
But I am unable to play it using my Android application.
If i run the same application on my smartphone (Nexus 5), it works.

How can I play a video file on Android Wearable using my android app.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting when you try to play the video?

Comment: Can't play the video file

Comment: This is the error message i see in the logs:
E/MediaPlayer(11335): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView(11335): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: I know that the same codecs are not available on Wear as they are on a regular phone. So you might need to encode the video differently. I've never tried this and do not know what is supported though.

Answer (score 1):

Android Wear only includes Audio codecs as of Android Wear 5.0 so the normal MediaPlayer APIs won't work. You need to roll your own using video libraries like ffmpeg, ...

Answer (score 1):

Finally I made it work. I don't know if this is something Android Wear specific or a bug, but it turns out that

```
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
File file = new File(path);
```

does not give access to the file on Android Wear devices.

Instead one has to convert the file into a temp file first:

```
InputStream ins = MainActivityBackup.this.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.hyperlapse2);
File tmpFile = null;
OutputStream output;

try {
    tmpFile = File.createTempFile("video","mov");
    output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
    int read;

    while ((read = ins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    ins.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then it can be loaded into a videoView

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(tmpFile.getPath());
```

Provided you are using your own video decoder or a library like ffmpeg or [vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/), since Android Wear does not support native video playback yet.

I implemented vitamio in roughly 5 minutes, if needed it can be imported via gradle dependency (look for it on [gradleplease](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#vitamio)). Built my app around vitamio videoView and it works like a charm. It can even play flash video.

Comment: I'm having some issues getting this to work, could I see your activity_main.xml ?

Comment: I don't have them anymore since it was only an experiment. The main activity xml was only a vitamio video view as far as I can remember, basically straight from the docs.

In the end, using vitamio did not prove successful either, since we needed to be able to scroll through the video frames, which did not work on android wear. Our fallback was an image sequence, which worked perfectly.